# including ascii art in python

Tags: python, printing, ascii

I am making a hangman program,
how can I include my art in the python
without typing print on every line
is there a multi-line print
like they have multi-line comments?
I don't mind importing all of the pictures
from a text file, can't figure this out from
the documentation, thanks for your help.

```
      def visual():
          if count = 1:
              ## shows the hanging ascii art
```

`

```
          ***************                                                
          *             *                                                
          *             *                                                
          *             *                                                
          *             *                                                
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
          *                                                              
  ***********************
```

one wrong

```
       ***************                                                
       *             *                                                
       *             *                                                
       *             *                                                
       *           ....                                               
       *           .  ..                                              
       *          ..   .                                              
       *          ..   .                                              
       *           .....                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *
```

---

two wrong

```
       ***************                                                
       *             *                                                
       *             *                                                
       *             *                                                
       *           ....                                               
       *           .  ..                                              
       *          ..   .                                              
       *          ..   .                                              
       *           .....                                              
       *             .                                                
       *       .......                                                
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *
```

---

`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `'''` or `"""` [triple-quoted string literal](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
longstring = """\
You can use multiple lines
and newlines
are preserved
"""
```

I used a `\` newline escape after the opening tripple-quote to avoid having to put the first line right after the opening quotes. The string thus starts at `You` (no newline before it):

```
>>> longstring = """\
... You can use multiple lines
... and newlines
... are preserved
... """
>>> print longstring
You can use multiple lines
and newlines
are preserved
```

Answer (score 1):

"like they can have multi-line comments":  There are no multi-line comments, only multi-line strings, and of course you can print them:

```
wrong_art[2] = """
       ***************                                                
       *             *                                                
       *             *                                                
       *             *                                                
       *           ....                                               
       *           .  ..                                              
       *          ..   .                                              
       *          ..   .                                              
       *           .....                                              
       *             .                                                
       *       .......                                                
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                                                              
       *                  
"""

print wrong_art[num_wrong]
```